# collaboration portal performance issue

Tags: 2007, windows-server, performance, collaboration

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 on Windows Server 2008. I am using collaboration portal template. I experienced issues when loading the same page multiple times, the page loading time is almost the same. I think if there could be cache function, it should be better (e.g. the 1st time of loading is slow, but if the content could be cached. The if we load from the 2nd time, since it is cached, it will be very fast from end user perspective.).

I read from this document that seems collaboration portal has no read cache? Is that correct? Any ideas how to enable read cache of collaboration portal?

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mossbiz/clarifications-collaboration-vs-publishing)

BTW: here is the related content of the document I refer to which mentions collaboration portal has no cache,

Publishing needs heavy branding, high performance read-only access (caching), staging and deployment, while Collaboration needs clear functionality, ease of engagement, consistency between sites and high performance read/write access (no caching, fast servers).

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup object, output and blob cache for your site collection in relation to site usage. See my answer earlier on this subject:

[SharePoint Web performance optimization](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/sharepoint-web-performance-optimization/3391#3391)

Publishing sites is usually web facing and allows anonymous access. This allows for a more agressive caching strategy, since site doesnt contain personalized items as a typical intranet does. In your typical collaboration site you need to take into account that content is personalized. If you cache those controls they will be shared amongst users. Hence you need a less agressive caching setting to avoid disclosing personal data across users.

Advanced scenarios in this area includes wrapping controls you dont want to cache with a substitution control, but this is a developer task and not simple to do.

About performance issues in general, make sure that you dont have alot of closed web parts on the page (add ?contents=1 to url). If your designers close web parts instead of deleting them this can severely affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related to your particular performance problem, but you may be helped by reading this post I wrote some time ago:  [A new approach to solve SharePoint’s painfully slow spin-up / start-up time for first request](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/04/new-approach-to-solve-sharepoints.html).

Comment: I think it is talking about STSADM, is it talking about collaboration portal web site itself?

Comment: The post I have linked to is talking about anything that uses the SharePoint Object Model, which includes STSADM and any SharePoint site.

Comment: I read the link and I think the root cause is CRL issue?

Comment: Possibly. Give it a try and see if it improves the situation.

Comment: Thank you Muhimbi! I will have a try when I come to office tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some techniques to Troubleshoot Page Loading Issues similar to Anders recommendation to check for closed web parts.  http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2010/01/troubleshooting-page-loading-issues.html

Comment: Thank you Mike! I will have a try when I come to office tomorrow.